# Autocomplete lambda expression (when it used like functions parameter) (C#, Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, visual-studio-2019

I can not get the development studio to substitute a lambda expression with the correct data as a parameter of the called function. How to do this?

I created a class that works with network requests. Three delegates are declared in this class and there is a function that makes a request to the server. The parameters of this function are: a command to the server and three callback functions (delegates). I pressed different combinations on the keyboard, but none of them allow substituting lambda functions automatically and I have to constantly fill everything with my hands.

http-manager:

```
namespace ProglotClientAdminPanel.managers
{
    public delegate void RequestCompletedCallBack(SimpleAnswer answer);
    public delegate void RequestSuccessCallback(SimpleAnswer answer);
    public delegate void RequestErrorCallback(SimpleAnswer answer, string errorMsg);


    public class ApiRequestHelperAsync
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// send request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="simpleCommandIn">SimpleCommand - command model</param>
        /// <param name="callBackIn">global callback</param>
        /// <param name="successCallbackIn">success callback</param>
        /// <param name="errorCallbackIn">error callback</param>
        public void sendRequest(SimpleCommand simpleCommandIn, 
            RequestCompletedCallBack callBackIn = null,
            RequestSuccessCallback successCallbackIn = null, RequestErrorCallback errorCallbackIn = null)
        {
            simpleCommand = simpleCommandIn;
            callBack = callBackIn;
            successCallback = successCallbackIn;
            errorCallback = errorCallbackIn;
            sendRequestToServer();//send http-request to server
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I make http-request with lambda-callback (it works):

```
SimpleCommand command = new SimpleCommand("saveStock");
command.addParam("org_id", user.org_id);
command.addParam("user_id", user.user_id);
command.addParam("stock", editableStock);

new ApiRequestHelperAsync().sendRequest(command,
    null,
    (SimpleAnswer answer) =>
    {

    },
    (SimpleAnswer answer, string errorMsg) =>
    {

    }
    );
```

How to force Visual Studio (2017 or 2019) to paste function lambda-param using keyboard combination?

```
    (SimpleAnswer answer) =>
    {

    },
    (SimpleAnswer answer, string errorMsg) =>
    {

    }
```

As you understand, code snippet is not good solution, because function or http-class may be changed at any project.

Answer (score 0):

So, I see only one solution: always update own code snippets for actual versions of class. My variant for this question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Simple API http-request (2 callbacks)</Title>
            <Shortcut>httpLambded_2callbacks</Shortcut>
            <Description>Make simple http-request with 2 lambda-callbacks</Description>
            <Author>Lunev N.F.</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[
            new ApiRequestHelperAsync().sendRequest(command,
                null,
                (SimpleAnswer answer) =>
                {
                    //on success

                },
                (SimpleAnswer answer, string errorMsg) =>
                {
                    //on error

                }
                );      
            ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```